# How to use a project as a library in the classpath in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

The referenced library is not functional, and I want to use the equivalent project in my workspace instead. Is there any way to do this without turning it into a library?

Eclipse Workspace:

[image: Eclipse Workspace]

Comment: Add the project to the Projects page of the Java Build Path in the project Properties

Comment: That did the job. Truly thankful. I apologize for the rudimentary nature of my question.